# Is there a way to make linux pass ls require decryption?

Tags: password-management, macos

So [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/), the standard unix password manager is great and I've started to use it to encrypt my passwords. But there is one thing that bugs me. When you run `pass ls` it shows you all your identities. I know it's not the passwords. But this still doesn't allow true anonymity, because if someone were to get hold of your computer, they could trace various accounts to you, even though they would not be able to get the password without your passphrase.

Now I can encrypt the `~/.password-store/` folder myself using `gpg-zip` and delete the original. Then when I need to use `pass` I could decrypt/unzip the folder and delete it again when I'm done but that is very tedious to do.

**Update 1:**

I'm using a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sentence of the `pass` website:

> Password management should be simple and follow Unix philosophy. With pass, each password lives inside of a gpg encrypted file whose filename is the title of the website or resource that requires the password

In other words, no, encrypting these within `pass` is not technologically possible. `pass` depends on the file name to be the account name.

Personally: You could have a 100MB filesystem image that you encrypt with AES, through `cryptsetup` / LUKS. It will only be readable for as long as you mount that filesystem – as soon as you unmount it, the files contained in that filesystem cease to "exist" at their known position.

Comment: Or you could run something like ecryptfs on top of whatever you are using. The bare files will then have meaningless names.

Comment: The thing is that I'm on Mac. Should most probable have mentioned that.

Comment: @Openbaringen I'm willing to bet there's encrypted file systems on OS X, too!

Comment: @MarcusMüller There is a way to do it via the disk utility(doesn't seem to support folder with a . infront) or via gpg-zip. But yeah it's not what I hoped for. Going to mark you answer as correct, because it technically answers my question.

Comment: @Openbaringen I'm absolutely sure there's other ways to have encrypted volumes on OS X – but I'm absolutely not an OS X person, so :(